# Custom Font in Silverlight OOB

Tags: silverlight, fonts, silverlight-oob

Can anyone give me a hand on how to use Custom fonts in a Silverlight app in OOB? It works in the browser correctly.

Furthermore, the font is working and referenced correctly as the designer renders what I am after, but when running the app it is ignored.

Thanks heaps

Edit :

Trying to emulate a Mutlimeter display (thus OOB)

FontFamily="/BNA;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Crystal"

Font Properties Build Action = **"Resource"**, Copy to Output Directory = **"Copy Always"**

Comment: Can you add your code so that we can see where you are making the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted, had to embed in to the client app side using

FontFamily="/BNA;component/Crysta.ttf#Crystal" and setting the Font as a Resource